# Google places api autoComplete not showing dropdown

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I have a simple grails application which has a form. For a requirement, i'm adding cities, state to an input field. I'm using Google places api to autocomplete the input field. The code in my gsp is as follows.

```
<label for="city">
     <input id="city" name="city">
</label>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places&key=myKey"></script>
<script>
$( "#city" ).autocomplete({

  source: function( request, response ) {
    var input = document.getElementById('city');
    var autoComplete= new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

  },
  minLength: 3
} );
</script>
```

When I execute this, nothing happens. No drop down comes up. Am i missing something? i'm quite new to this API

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you don't need to write `autocomplete` by yourself google map will take care of it.

So remove your `autocomplete` code and add just below code

```
<script>
    var input = document.getElementById('city');
    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
</script>
```

Comment: For the question I added, this answer is a good solution. If in plain html, when I use this code, it works as expected. But in my gsp, I see no results. No action takes place when I type something.

Comment: Can you create the `JSFiddle` of your code ? I will take a look at it
(Its ok if don't want to create as key is private one in that case just add the whole code in question).

Comment: The issue was a mistake from my end, when using the keys. It's working as expected. Thanks for the quick answer